# Customize resource routing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, resources

think of the resource routing of a `photo`-class for example.

If I this to my `routes.rb` I will get following routes:

```
resources :photos

# GET '/photos/', :to => 'photos#index'
# GET '/photos/:photo_id/, :to => 'photos#show'
# and so on and so on
```

Now what I want is to replace the word `/photos` in all the routes with a simple `/p` so that I can get a short URL like `/p/1` for the first photo. Is there a way to simply alter the `resource`-line or do I have to manually add each route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make all your routes via `:photos` through `p`

```
resources :p, :controller => "photos"
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more concise and avoid the issue with `p_id`, you could do it like this :

```
resources :photos, path: 'p'
```

This way, you benefits from the readibility on your end (it will generate helpers like `edit_photo_path`, you will access variables as `photo_id` in case of a nested route and such) and generate the named URLs you do want.